# Restore NSManagedObject relationships in background threads

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nsoperation

I'm developing an application through Core Data and I need to perform some calculation in a background thread to create an xml file based on specific `NSManagedObject`.

Following the documentation, I set up `NSOperation` subclass. This class has a property like the following:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray* objectIDs;
```

where `objectIDs` is an array of managed object ids (of type `NSManagedObjectID`). This is necessary according to the documentation: `NSManagedObject` are not thread safe.

Inside the `main` of `NSOperation` subclass I'm doing the following:

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

NSManagedObjectContext *exportContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
[exportContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:[self persistentStoreCoordinator]];

for (NSManagedObjectID* objectID in self.orderObjectIDs) {

    NSError* error = nil;
    Order* order = (Order*)[exportContext existingObjectWithID:objectID error:&error];

    // order.someRelationship is fault here...

    // Create XML file here...
}

[exportContext reset];
[exportContext release], exportContext = nil;

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kRegisterComplete object:self];

[pool drain];
pool = nil;
```

Inside the `for` loop I'm fetching the right object using `existingObjectWithID:error` method of `NSManagedObjectContext` class since

> Unlike objectWithID:, this method never returns a fault.

The method works. I'm able to retrieve the properties of that retrieved object. The only problem is that relationships are fetched as faults.

Said this, I have two questions.

First, is this the right approach to fecth `NSManagedObject` in a background thread?
Then, how can I fetch relationships for each fetched object within the `for` loop? Do I have to create a `NSFetchedRequest` to fetch the relationship object based on the specific object that has been fetched through the id?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you care that the relationship is a fault? Accessing it will fill the fault and return the data, are you concerned about disk I/O for some reason?

You may try using prefetching to alleviate some of the I/O overhead, but it's utility is limited to the relationship on the entity being fetched:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/NSFetchRequest.html

In that case you would create a fetch request with a predicate like so:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF == %@", objectID];
```

That will return to you only the managed object you desire, and with relationship pre-fetching the relationship won't be a fault.

You could further optimize this by using a IN clause and fetching all the objects at once:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF IN (%@)", desiredObjectIDs];
```

Comment: +1 for your suggestion. Are you saying that I could create a *NSFetchRequest* and prefecthing relationships using *setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching:*? I'm new in Core Data and I have not clear when faults are fulfilled. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, you could create the fetch request and pass an NSArray of the desired relationship key paths, i.e. [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"someRelationship"]. That will cause the fault to be fulfilled when the fetch happens, thereby eliminating the extra I/O.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure of the following:

- Before you pass around any object IDs you do - `[NSManagedObjectContext obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:error:]` on the originating thread.

(on main thread)

```
[managedObjectContext obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:objectIDs error:nil]
```

- Before attempting to access these objects from another thread (including their relationships) you need to save the NSManagedObjectContext of the originating thread. Otherwise the objects will not exist in persistence and your background thread will be unable to fetch it (or other relationships). Is easiest way to insure this is to call a blocking save on the main thread at the beginning of your NSOperation execution. For example:

`dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        [managedObjectContext save:nil];
    });`

You may make an NSFetchRequest or access the relationships directly depending on which way is more convenient; probably accessing the relationships directly. You do not need to call a `[NSManagedObjectContext reset]` at the end of your routine.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Managed objects have already saved in the store, so I don't need to call *obtainPermanentIDsForObjects*, I think. Then, can you explain why I don't need to call *[NSManagedObjectContext reset]*?

Comment: Reset discards and invalidates the NSManagedObjects on that particular context. (Discards unsaved changes, invalidates all instances of NSManagedObjects) Since you're releasing the context anyways that step is redundant.